# Has sending emails with the smtplib changed at all?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I know that python compatibility with gmail changes all the time when google does things that make it harder for other 'apps' to access the email. For the purposes of this code I have created a brand new account with **Less secure app access enabled**. There is no 2 step verification on this account, so naturally there is no app-specific password functionality, and the email password I use should be my email's actual password (at least I think?).

Sidenote I have also taken these steps to remove security from my account
[image]

I was following instructions from a fairly recent guide on using python to send gmail https://pybit.es/python-smtplib.html

with the following example code provided:

```
import smtplib

smtp_server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp_server.ehlo()
smtp_server.starttls()
smtp_server.login('pybitesblog@gmail.com', '<App Password>')

smtp_server.sendmail('pybitesblog@gmail.com', 'recipient@gmail.com', 'Subject: Happy Australia Day!\nHi Everyone! Happy Australia Day! Cheers, Julian')

smtp_server.quit()
print('Email sent successfully')
```

Whenever I run the exact code wiith the expected things replaced, my code ends up hanging and the email never gets sent. Does anyone know as of right now, what code will work?

Alright for whatever reason 10 minutes later the emails show up in my sent mail box despite me terminating both times and the emails were successfully delivered, just into my spam folder. I am still unable to reproduce this, and I don't know exactly what code sent those emails. It had to be some form of the code I posted above, however, because the emails I got had that specific message that other websites with alternative methods obviously weren't using.

Comment: Does adding ```From: ``` and ```To: ``` to the email text change anything? Like [this](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/) tutorial shows

Comment: No, those are only for formatting purposes - something I tweaked last night made it work and I can't figure out what